# Oracle Query IN clause dynamic

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

`select A_VALUE from S_Profile where A_NAME = 'TN_I';`

Please note that `A_VALUE` and `A_NAME` columns are `varchar2`
Above select query give me result as `1,2`

I have another table

`select count(*) from TRING where T_EX in (1,2)` => it give me some 1222 (some result)

I want to use (where in clause values are coming from other query)

`select count(*) from TRING where T_EX in ( select A_VALUE from S_Profile where A_NAME = 'TN_I' );` => `ORA-01722: invalid number`

T_EX column is NUMBER(38,0)

How do I write query to use it in this way ?

Comment: did you try parsing `A_VALUE` to a number?

Comment: in the inner query, replace `select A_VALUE` with `select to_number(A_VALUE)`

Comment: @ODDminus1 : It wont work as A_VALUE is 1,2 in table -S_Profile

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splitting the string into rows using `regexp_substr`and `CONNECT BY` and regular expressions

```
    WITH cte as (
      SELECT distinct trim(regexp_substr(A_VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, level)) ID
      FROM (SELECT A_VALUE FROM S_Profile where A_NAME = 'TN_I') t
      CONNECT BY instr(A_VALUE, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0
    )
    select count(*) 
    from TRING where T_EX in ( select ID from cte);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dj3jfzoV)

Answer (score 0):

Split `A_VALUE` into rows:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM tring
 WHERE t_ex IN (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (a_value,
                                          '[^,]+',
                                          1,
                                          LEVEL)
                      FROM s_profile
                     WHERE a_name = 'TN_I'
                CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (a_value, ',') + 1);
```

This presumes that subquery returns only one row (i.e. only one `A_VALUE`) for certain `A_NAME`. If that's not the case, say so - it isn't difficult to fix it:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM tring
 WHERE t_ex IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (a_value,
                                      '[^,]+',
                                      1,
                                      COLUMN_VALUE)
                  FROM s_profile
                       CROSS JOIN
                       TABLE (
                          CAST (
                             MULTISET (
                                    SELECT LEVEL
                                      FROM DUAL
                                CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                                           REGEXP_COUNT (a_value, ',') + 1)
                                AS SYS.odcinumberlist))
                 WHERE a_name = 'TN_I');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't split the string into rows (as that is slow), just match on a sub-string (including surrounding delimiters so you match complete terms):

```sql
SELECT count(*)
FROM   TRING t
WHERE  EXISTS( 
         SELECT 1
         FROM   S_Profile s
         WHERE  s.a_name = 'TN_I'
         AND    ',' || s.a_value || ',' LIKE '%,' || t.t_ex || ',%'
       );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tring (t_ex) AS
  SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 611 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 611 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 611;

CREATE TABLE s_profile (a_name, a_value) AS
  SELECT 'TN_I', '1,2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COUNT(*) |
| --- |
| 1222 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CKaRnEL7)

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain it. I am not getting an expected output from this query.

Comment: @VJS `LIKE` is used to find sub-string matches. All it does is count the rows in `TRING` where the row is a sub-string of the `a_value` row in `S_Profile` (with the surrounding `,` delimiters so that it matches complete terms). I've added a fiddle which shows it working. If you do not get the expected output then check that you do not have spaces in (or trailing) your `a_value` or `t_ex` strings.

Comment: @VJS If you are having trouble with white space then [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k-gO1l_y) has various solutions. If it is something else then you need to identify what is causing the problem and provide a [MRE].

Answer (score 0):

Since your `A_VALUE` column is string of comma separated values, so you could not use `IN` condition to check if it contains a number value (of column `T_EX`).
You could try to use [REGEXP_INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions162.htm#SQLRF06300) function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TRING t 
WHERE EXISTS 
     (SELECT 1 
      FROM S_Profile s
      WHERE s.A_NAME = 'TN_I' 
            AND REGEXP_INSTR(s.A_VALUE, '(^|\D)' || t.T_EX || '($|\D)') > 0);
```

The regex pattern is used to make sure that value `1` is only matched to `1`, not to `10`,`100`...

Comment: If the OP is expecting to match integers then would the pattern `'(^|\D)' || t.T_EX || '($|\D)'` not be better? Or for comma-delimited strings ``'(^|,)' || t.T_EX || '($|,)'``? (Although you can avoid regular expressions, as they are slow, and instead use simple string comparisons such as the `SUBSTR` function or the `LIKE` operator, which are much faster, if you also match the surrounding delimiters).

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited regexp pattern in my answer.